# Integration of Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function

How to show that the integration:
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-bx^2}\,dx=\left(\frac1b\right)^{(n+1)/2}\cdot {\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \over 2}$$

Comment: Make change $t=b x^2$ and use the definition of $\Gamma$ function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we recall the definition of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function): $$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx.$$

To simplify $$\int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-bx^2}\,dx$$ we use the change of variables

\begin{align*}
u &= bx^{2} \implies x = \sqrt{\frac{u}{b}}\\
du &= 2bx\,dx = 2b\sqrt{\frac{u}{b}}\,dx \implies dx = \frac{1}{2b}\left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{-1/2}.
\end{align*}

This gives us
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}e^{-bx^{2}}\,dx &= \frac{1}{2b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{n/2}e^{-u}\,du\\[5pt]
&=\frac{1}{2b}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{-u}\,du\\[5pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{(n+1)/2}\int_0^{\infty}u^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1}e^{-u}\,du\\[5pt]
&= \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{(n+1)/2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2}.
\end{align*}